# Many to many relationships store and update in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I create three tables:

### Post Table

id--title--body

### Tags Table

id--name

### post_tag

post_id--tag_id

### Post Model

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
}
```

### Tag Model

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
}
```

> This is a many to many relation

I want to store tags when add new post and update tags when update post, and I use bootstrap-tagsinput plugin, for add post,I use this method to store the new tags:

```
public function storeTags($post, $tags)
{
    $tagInputArr = explode(',', $tags);
    $tagArr = [];
    foreach ($tagInputArr as $tag) {
        $tagArr[] = new Tag(['name' => $tag]);
    }
    $post->tags()->saveMany($tagArr);
}
```

> $post is the new post object, $tags is the tag string from $request.

For update post,I have a problem,when I view the edit post page,the default tags is selected from database,If I want to add new tags the storeTags method is not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing like this in `storeTags()`

```
$post->save();
if (isset($request->tags)) {
    $post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);
} else {
    $post->tags()->sync(array());
}
```

In `updateTags()`

```
$post->save();
if (isset($request->tags)) {
    $post->tags()->sync($request->tags);
} else {
    $post->tags()->sync(array());
}
```

In you html file for the tags, use this

```
<select class="form-control select2-multi" name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach ($tags as $tag)
        <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

There is a difference that in `sync()` method for update no need of the second parameter.

I recommend you to [watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mL_7im7CBOE&index=42&list=PLwAKR305CRO-Q90J---jXVzbOd4CDRbVx) this whole playlist of tag creating

Comment: sync method's parameter is tags' id,but $request->tags is tags' name

Comment: Sorry,Maybe my question is not clear enough,What I want to do is delete or add tags when I add new post.Like wordpress's tag CRUD.

Comment: @ChenLee you want to know how to delete the Tags??

Comment: In this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mL_7im7CBOE&index=42&list=PLwAKR305CRO-Q90J---jXVzbOd4CDRbVx),all tags are created when I add new post or update  an existed post,But if I want to add new tags or delete existed tags when I update an existed post, how can I write method use sync.